# Protocol buffers Fieldmask on Collections within resource

Tags: protocol-buffers

If I want to update the "amount" field within a particular element inside  "f_units" collection in the below resource (protocol buffer), how will the FieldMask look like to update the amount field? Does the field mask operate on array index for collections?

```
{
  "f_sel": {
    "f_units": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "amount": {
          "coefficient": 1000,
          "exponent": -2
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "amount": {
          "coefficient": 2000,
          "exponent": -2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Will it be "f_sel.f_units.0.amount" ? How can I update the amount using FieldMask?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to replace individual elements of a repeated field with an index in a FieldMask.

Instead, you'd update the amount field for the element within f_units you wish to change and set the FieldMask to

```
"f_sel.f_units"
```

It would be slightly more efficient to only have to send a delta to the original list, but it would be hard to prevent bugs.  For example, what if the proto was modified in the meantime and the specified index (presuming there was a way to specify one) for the repeated field was no longer in range?

As an aside, [Google does propose the concept of MergeOptions](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskUtil.java) which defines semantics for how repeated fields are to be handled when merging.  Currently, it appears they intend for you either to replace the repeated field in its entirety or append to the end of the destination field.  Both of these merging strategies avoid the aforementioned bug that could be caused by specifying an invalid index.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @Michael. I will be introducing the path as part of a request to an API call which I am designing, hence I can only expect the client to pass me the delta for the "amount" field for a specific position within the collection.